# Why are my AWS S3 object counts different

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im new to AWS S3 and have recently made copies of numerous S3 buckets.

everything seemed to work fine however some of the new destination S3 buckets object counts do not match the source S3 buckets.

The S3 buckets in question have multiple sub folders, where the the counts differ and are small I can manually check. It appears the source counts are wrong in these cases as the count reported is 8 when in fact I only have 7 objects in total present. The new S3 destination bucket reports 7 objects.

In other cases there are 1000's of objects and I cannot manually check.

Where there is a discrepancy the source count is always bigger than the destination count.

I've a feeling these discrepancies are caused by objects that have been deleted in the past from the source S3 buckets and the count is not refreshed to reflect this.

Does AWS S3 have a function/process that can reset the S3 bucket object counts?

How can I ensure all the source objects have been copied to my new S3 destination S3 buckets?

To obtain the counts I employed the following AWS S3 Management Console function...

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code out?

Comment: @TonyYip i didnt employ any "code" I used the S3 Management Console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this before. The discrepancy is normally due to the 'folders'.

When a user clicks the "Create folder" button in the S3 management console, it creates a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. This 'forces' S3 to display the folder even when it is empty.

Amazon S3 does not actually need folders to be created (in fact, they don't actually exist!). Depending upon how you copied the objects between buckets, **these zero-length objects might not have been copied**.

You can easily test this in the small bucket you have. Just list the bucket and look for zero-length objects like this:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query 'Contents[].[Key,Size]' --output text
```